# Can wiping and reinstalling OS damage the SSD?

Tags: ssd, install

Computer is new 13" retina MBP. 2.9GHz i5, 16GB RAM, 256GB SSD.

I have been working on some dotfile setup scripts for my new computer and thought I had them dialed in, but did not really work how I wanted. So I restarted, hit CMD+R and chose "reinstall Yosemite" because I wanted to try again.

It just occurred to me I was not sure if doing that, repeatedly if needed, can cause any issues with the hard drive or anything?

Comment: how repentantly ?

Comment: Just did it once so far, maybe 1 or 2 more times if needed. Don't know a better way to test the scripts... :/

Comment: It should be OK than :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to do that at least a couple hundred times to even remotely becoming an issue.

There was an [article](http://uk.hardware.info/reviews/4178/10/hardwareinfo-tests-lifespan-of-samsung-ssd-840-250gb-tlc-ssd-updated-with-final-conclusion-final-update-20-6-2013) on hardware.info where these guys put some SSDs through some torture tests and ended up "writing" what equated to about 22 years of data.

The bottom line is that the drive's reliability will outlast your ability to fill it up and buy a newer bigger one.